# TikZ controls cause false alarms about overfull \hboxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, errors, warnings

The following code

```
Then $e+F$ acts in the standard representation (on $\mathbb C^{mn+k}$) in such a way
that we can decompose this action into the following pieces:

for even $m$,
$$
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,scale=1.25,every node/.style={anchor=south}]
\node (1) at (-4,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (2) at (-3,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (l) at (-2,0) {$\cdots\vphantom{\mathbb C^n}$};
\node (m/2) at (-1,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node at (0,0) {$\mathbb C^k$};
\node (-m/2) at (1,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (-l) at (2,0) {$\cdots\vphantom{\mathbb C^n}$};
\node (-2) at (3,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (-1) at (4,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\draw (1) -- node[above] {$e_1$} (2);
\draw (2) -- node[above] {$e_2$} (l);
\draw (l) -- node[above] {$e_{\frac m2-1}$} (m/2);
\draw (m/2) .. controls (-.2,.8) and (.2,.8) .. node[above] {$e_{\frac m2}$} (-m/2);
\draw (-m/2) -- node[above] {$e_{\frac m2+1}$} (-l);
\draw (-l) -- node[above] {$e_{m-2}$} (-2);
\draw (-2) -- node[above] {$e_{m-1}$} (-1);
\draw (-1) .. controls (7,-.5) and (-7,-.5) .. node[below] {$F$} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
```

produces

[image]

accompanied with the warning about "Overfull \hbox (43.07889pt too wide)", although the picture fits pretty well within margins. I presume this happens because TikZ controls involve invisible angle for the Bezier curve that is outside margins. But it is invisible, so the warning is actually redundant.

I realize this is a minor (maybe nonexistent) issue, but still - could something be done to avoid such messages?

Comment: Take a look at the `use as bounding box` option on page 124 of the `pfgmanual`.

Comment: @S Wow this was quick!

Comment: Coincidence, but thanks :)

Comment: @Skillmon I have manual for 3.0.1a, there it is on page 175 (section 15.8), with examples; there is also a version `\useasboundingbox`. All in all, - don't you want to make this an answer? I believe it can be useful for others too, no?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `$$` for displayed maths, instead one should use `\[` and `\]` in LaTeX.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes I know - I just keep forgetting as I learned about it too late. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two known issues mentioned in the pgfmanual of version 3.0.1a on page 124 related to the size of the bounding box:

> First, the line thickness of diagonal lines is not taken into account correctly. Second, control
>   points of a curve often lie far “outside” the curve and make the bounding box too large. In this case, you should use the `[use as bounding box]` option.

In this specific question the second reason is at fault, because the control points lie outside the actually visible figure, but are considered for the bounding box.

The command `\useasboundingbox` can also be used, which is an abbreviation for `\path[use as bounding box]`. The easiest way to set a bounding box is the use of something like:

```
\path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
```

Of course the correct coordinates differ from picture to picture.

In this specific case `(-5,-.8)` and `(5,1.2)` seem to provide good results:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,scale=1.25,every node/.style={anchor=south}]
\path[use as bounding box] (-5,-.8) rectangle (5,1.2);
\node (1) at (-4,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (2) at (-3,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (l) at (-2,0) {$\cdots\vphantom{\mathbb C^n}$};
\node (m/2) at (-1,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node at (0,0) {$\mathbb C^k$};
\node (-m/2) at (1,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (-l) at (2,0) {$\cdots\vphantom{\mathbb C^n}$};
\node (-2) at (3,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\node (-1) at (4,0) {$\mathbb C^n$};
\draw (1) -- node[above] {$e_1$} (2);
\draw (2) -- node[above] {$e_2$} (l);
\draw (l) -- node[above] {$e_{\frac m2-1}$} (m/2);
\draw (m/2) .. controls (-.2,.8) and (.2,.8) .. node[above] {$e_{\frac m2}$} (-m/2);
\draw (-m/2) -- node[above] {$e_{\frac m2+1}$} (-l);
\draw (-l) -- node[above] {$e_{m-2}$} (-2);
\draw (-2) -- node[above] {$e_{m-1}$} (-1);
\draw (-1) .. controls (7,-.5) and (-7,-.5) .. node[below] {$F$} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]